# Login Screen Autobrightness

Tags: 20.04, login, screen, brightness

Is there a way to completely disable the autobrightness in Ubuntu 20.04? I mean, I already disabled it in my desktop, but it seems to be enabled on the login screen, so I have to manually increase the brightness every time I boot my laptop. I tried creating a script with this command

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1
```

(`eDP-1` is my screen's name). The command works, but I noticed that the system brightness won't change. You can see a brighter screen, but the brightness slide will stay the same. Actually, if I put `1` as the value, the brightness will remain the same, no matter the current system brightness percentage.
I also didn't find any option in dconf Editor to solve this.